# Telegram Group Filtering

Tags: full-text-search, filtering, telegram, groupchat

I've been using an open source version of Telegram called Bettergram, which claims to be the same protocols. Whether that is true or not to the side, I realized that even though Telegram does not allow pornography, there's a crap ton of it floating around. Is it possible to build a small edit into the code of bettergram (being that it is open-source) to have it block or not register chats or groups that have certain keywords within them(explicit results within group would trigger to be blocked).If this is possible, how hard is it (and can someone help me.) Thanks guys! :) link: https://github.com/bettergram/bettergram

Comment: Couldn't invest so much effort into reworking a whole TG client, so I took a python TG client and literally just added an if statement with keywords to auto remove the user from the joined group.